# ¿Como alíneo verticalmente dos elementos div, que estan dentro de un div padre?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo una tabla y dentro de un td tengo un div con dos dos elementos.

```
<td class="align-middle">
  <div style="flex;">
    
    <div class="ancho-columna">
      <input type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning text-center m-auto alert-unidades" role="alert">
      Mensaje
    </div>          

  </div>
</td>
```

Cómo hago para alinear verticalmente el input y el mensaje? Es que me queda bastante bien, pero el mensaje me aparece ligeramente hacia abajo comparado con el input.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Si estás usando Bootstrap, deberías usar sus recomendaciones: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#horizontal-form o https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#inline-forms

Answer (score 1):

El `td` va a aplicar el estilo para lo que esté dentro, en este caso tu primer `div`. Por eso, tu `div` padre o contenedor de los otros 2 `div` es quien tendría que tener el estilo para alinear verticalmente el contenido. Probé esto rapidamente, espero que resuelva para tu escenario.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.inner-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">

  <div class="inner-container">
    <input type="number" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="inner-container">
    <p>This text is centered.</p>
    <img src="https://animalgiftclub-static.myshopblocks.com/images/2019/03/contain/256x256/5a89a3cdfc269fbc4198a5a79e9b009a.jpg" alt="alternatetext">
  </div>

</div>
```

> Edición: se agrega bordes a los elementos `div` para mejor visualización

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero ahi lo estas centrando horizontalmente, no?

Comment: @FranciscoMicucci no no, eso sería vertical fijate que si ejecutas el código aparece un `div` debajo del otro. Horizontalmente sería (de izquierda a derecha) uno al lado del otro.

Comment: @FranciscoMicucci ahí le agregué bordes para que puedas verlo mejor. Si lo que buscas es alinearlos horizontalmente deberías convertir el `div` en un elemento **inline**